# Logically，double sumOfList(List<? extends Double> list) will make the function become read-only mode , why list.remove() can be compiled successfully

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, extends

Logically，`static double sumOfList(List<? extends Double> list)` will make the function become read-only mode ，then why `list.remove()` can be compiled successfully

```
public class Extend_char {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
        List<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();        
        list.add(1.2);        
        list.add(2.2);        
        list.add(3.2);        
        System.out.println(sumOfList(list));                
        System.out.println(list);    
}
    static double sumOfList(List<? extends Double> list) {
        double sum = 0;        
            for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
            double n = list.get(i);            
            sum = sum + n;        
            }
            //list.add(new Double(5.5));  Cannot compile and call normally                    
            list.remove(2.2);   //Can compile and call normally        
            return sum;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Logically，static double sumOfList(List<? extends Double> list) will make the function become read-only mode

See, that's the problem with programming. It's too complicated - so we provide oversimplified explanations.

You've been the victim of this. `List<? extends Double>` is **not** a 'read only list'.

But I can see how someone who was trying to be helpful told you that it was.

See, the point of `List<? extends Something>` is that it lets you provide a `List<Something>`, or a `List<SomeChildOfSomething>`. *IF* it is then possible to invoke `.add(instanceOfSomething)` on such a thing, that's problem.

Imagine this method:

```
void foo(List<? extends Number> list) {
   list.add(5); // an integer
}

List<Double> listOfDoubles = new ArrayList<Double>();
foo(listOfDoubles);
listOfDoubles.get(0); // oh dear. Now what?
```

See the problem? A solution is to ensure that **all methods that would fail unless they know the precise type** are disallowed. `add` is such a method. So is `addAll` and `set` for obvious reasons. You can't invoke those unless you know the list is either of the exact type of the expression you're passing to those methods, or a supertype of it (which is why you *can* invoke `.add` on a `List<? super Double>` just fine).

But the methods that modify the list which do *not* cause such issues - basically everything that doesn't take a (collection of) elements of type T, such as `.clear()`, `.remove()`, `removeIf`, etc?

Those are just fine.

TL;DR: `List<? extends AThingie>` is not 'a read only list'. That's completely wrong. It is an understandable but oversimplified explanation though. Don't be too harsh on who told you this.